# Sync settings in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am looking to sync bookmarks between devices, the configuration options for sync used to be in Advanced Settings but it seems to have changed.

I am currently using this version:

Google Chrome   52.0.2743.116 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

How does one sync on newer versions of chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right up at the top of the settings page under "Advanced sync settings":

[image: Advanced sync settings]

Comment: Has this functionality gone away? Can't find it